# Undesirable long number rounding in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, numbers, jsfiddle, rounding

How can it be possible, Chrome `floor`ing the last `1` in a long number:

```
var a = 12345678987654321;
console.log("a =",a); // Traces: 12345678987654320
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zAXLx/

[image]

Comment: This answer could help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/is-there-a-good-javascript-bigdecimal-library

Comment: http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[All numbers in JavaScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19) are [IEEE-754 double-precision numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), which have a maximum number of ~15 significant digits. It's not Chrome, it's the nature of IEEE-754 double-precision floating point. When numbers get really big like that, they start becoming imprecise.